# Creating a Doctrine behavior: How to access actAs() params from within a listener object

Tags: doctrine, listener, doctrine-1.2

I'm creating a behavior (one template and one listener). In the template class, I'm using the addListener() method to attach the listener to the model.

```
// Inside the template's setTableDefinition() method
$this->addListener(new RemoraSaveListener);
```

Pretty standard stuff, it seems.

From within the listener, how to I access the template options that have been set using the model's actAs() method? You know, the ones that automatically occupy the _options property of the template object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template class should have a `protected $_options = array()` property.

Pass this property to your listener, like so:

```
$this->addListener(new RemoraSaveListener($this->_options));
```

In your listener class you should also have a `protected $_options` property.

Add this to your listener:

```
public function __construct($options) {
    $this->_options = $options;
}
```

You should now be able to access the options from within your listener class (e.x from within a `preSave` call).